# Authentication action not working redirect not working

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization

Learning authentication and authorization.

I have a secret page which i have decorated with the attribute [Authorize] in my controller like so:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Secret()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Authenticate()
    {
        var grandmaClaims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "Bob@bobm.com"),
            new Claim("Grandma.says", "very nice boi")
        };

        var lincenseClaim = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob "),
            new Claim("DrivingLicense", "A+")
        };

        var grandmaIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(grandmaClaims, "Grandma Identity");
        var licenseIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(lincenseClaim, "Government");

        var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new [] {grandmaIdentity});

        HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

However when i go to https://localhost:44327/home/secret I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
```

However I am pretty sure I had done what is expected in my start up to get this working:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication("cookieAuth")
            .AddCookie("CookieAuth", config =>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "Grandmas.Cookie";
                config.LoginPath = "/Home/Authenticate";

            });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

        });
    }
}
```

why isnt authenticate() action being called?

and please no opinions on cookie security, this is just for learning purposes

Answer (score 0):

found it out!!!

```
        services.AddAuthentication("cookieAuth")
            .AddCookie("CookieAuth", config =>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "Grandmas.Cookie";
                config.LoginPath = "/Home/Authenticate/";

            });
```

cookieAuth and CookieAuth.... was a foolish uppercase typo, both should have been matching. i.e CookieAuth!!